# How to fix urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> error?

Tags: python, request, python-requests, urllib, urllib2

I'm setting a python unshort url code and I want 
I want the long version of the shorted URLs in a file to be written on the screen.
There is no hassle when a normal URL arrives.
But I get an error when a malicious URL arrives.

I use the following code:

```
import requests
import urllib
dosya=open("urller.txt","r")
satirlar=dosya.readlines()
for satir in satirlar:
    resp = urllib.urlopen(satir)
    print(resp.url)
dosya.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the script to complete successfully you want to add error handling. Maybe something like the following:

```
import requests
import urllib
dosya=open("urller.txt","r")
satirlar=dosya.readlines()
for satir in satirlar:
    try:
        resp = urllib.urlopen(satir)
        print(resp.url)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("Failed to open URL {0} Reason: {1}".format(satir, e.reason))
dosya.close()
```

This code will print all valid response URLs. For any invalid URL it will instead print an error report.